# FirebaseAuth requests from this iOS client application are blocked?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am getting error while using FirebaseAuth method `PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber`. The error is

> Requests from this iOS client application  are blocked.Reason
>   Forbidden and status permission denied.

What to do?

Comment: Hello, did you get a chance to resolve this issue?

Comment: Nah , i remember sending them a email about this, then just hitting a wall. Later on i created a new project on firebase console and linked app to it.